# Symfony 1.4 CSRF TOKEN protection for AJAX forms

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, csrf-protection

I have an AJAX form that I wish to be protected with the CSRF TOKEN on submit.

My question is, How do I validate it in my action?

I can successfully send it over via my AJAX call but the problem is validating it on my action.

I know that

```
 $request->checkCSRFProtection();
```

Doesn't work since it is for the link_to function.

Is there a way for me to validate it on my action?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you use the build-in validation of the form the CSRF field will be validated as well. There's no need for any additional code.

Comment: hi Michal, thanks! But I'm looking into custom validating the form field values from within my action. And I am hoping to validate the csrf_token along with the form values as well.